# send form values from child function component to parent class component

Tags: reactjs

I've learned that it's best to minimize the number of class components and to keep all the logic in as few components as possible. I've managed to create a to-do list that only has the 1 class component by putting this in the input tag of the SearchBar component:

```
onChange={e => props.updateVal(e.target.value)}
```

That does exactly what I want and sends that 1 piece of data back to the parent's updateVal function.

What I want to figure out is how to do this with 1 form submit that contains several inputs which are all text fields. Is it even possible? I'd like to stay away from refs and changing the component to a class. This is just practice for me as I get better at react and any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on making reusable components that can be used throughout your application.

For example, you can create your own reusable `input`:

```
import React from 'react';

// props will consist of "value", "onChange", "name" and a "placeholder"
const Input = props => <input type="text" {...props} />

export default Input;
```

Now create a `container` that handles all of the input's `values`;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Input from '../Input';

const fields = [
 {
   name: "company",
   placeholder: "Company"
 },
 {
   name: "email",
   placeholder: "Email"
 },
 {
   name: "firstName",
   placeholder: "First Name"
 },
 {
   name: "lastName",
   placeholder: "First Name"
 },
];

class Form extends Component {
  state = { firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "", company: "" };

  handleChange = ({ target: {name, value} }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });

  handleSubmit = e => {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert(JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4));
  }

  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     {fields.map(props => <Input key="props.name" onChange={this.handleChange} {...props} /> )}   
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );

};

 export default Form;
```

---

**Working example** (one `class` component and one reusable component -- click `Run code snippet`):

```js
const Input = props => <input type="text" {...props} />

const fields = [
  { name: "company", placeholder: "Company" },
  { name: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
  { name: "firstName", placeholder: "First Name" },
  { name: "lastName", placeholder: "First Name" }
];
    
class Form extends React.Component {
  state = { firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "", company: "" };
    
  handleChange = ({ target: {name, value} }) => this.setState({ [name]: value });
    
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 4));
  }
    
  render = () => (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      {fields.map(props => <Input key="props.name" onChange={this.handleChange} {...props}/>)}   
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You could take it a step further and make the `Form` reusable; although, it'll be harder to maintain as the form gets more complex with different inputs, field-level validations, and field styling.

I'd suggest learning how to utilize `class`es before you start jumping into the up-and-coming [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: This seems really straightforward, but I've come to realize with react that there are lots of different ways to do the same thing. Is this style considered best practice or is the best practice for forms decided by the senior dev at each company?

Comment: Recommend by the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components and a good practice. Minimize code and maximize reusability.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Redux-form with react for better form handling ,

[LIbrary Reference - Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/simple/)

[Watch This Tech Talk - Before Click Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDTi7lYR1VU)